# ext4 drives getting corrupted with Windows Reserved partition

Tags: windows, ext4

I don't know how it's happening, but I have 2 stand alone single partition ext4 drives that have been corrupted with "Windows Reserved" partitions.

I was having a hardware problem with a high speed drive that attaches to my mother board that had windows installed on it. I handed off my PC to my father who is decent with hardware. I pulled all my SSDs, one of which was my Linux installation. I accidentally left one of my hard drives in the PC which had ext4 partitioning and when we attempted to access the drive I looked and the drive was unreadable with a "Windows Reserved" partition on it. I thought he may have wrongly initialized the drive. I'm wrong, you'll see why below.

I asked him what he did to the PC while in his possession and he said "Just installed Windows and reset the BIOS to 'optimized defaults'". There is a setting in the BIOS for booting in LINUX and Windows, I think it was EFI?

Prior to him taking my system, I wasn't having a problem with anything other than Windows having issues with its own drive, which we fixed. Everything was working fine, I could access Windows, but not see the extEXT4 drive, and Linux used that drive exclusively. No problems.

Now I can't access my data, but I found another drive I had laying around which was a copy and attempted today to access that, and *another* "Windows Reserved Partition" popped up on this before I could access it, so it wasn't a mistaken initialization.

I don't understand why this his happening or how to fix it. I tried testdisk and it couldn't find files.

I've been really torn up over this because I don't know how to fix it, I've read up on so much and I don't have a real clear answer how to diagnose it or fix it. I have not written to either drive or done anything to them since they became corrupted.

I'm convinced the BIOS reset by him caused this, but I don't know what the settings were. This is really upsetting. I have data on both these corrupted drives that go back 20 years.

I don't know what else to do other than sort through recovered files from EaseUS Partition Master File Recovery. I'd like to get one of these drives back, but I suspect it isn't possible.

TLDR: I have 2 hard drives, formatted with ext4 that were corrupted with "Windows Reserved" partitions, I can't figure why this is happening or how to fix it. I have 1 drive with Linux and 1 drive with Windows. Neither of those are corrupted, just the storage drives.

Parted output:

[image]

Additional from TestDisk:

Finds partition, but unable to do anything with it.

TestDisk1:

[image]

TestDisk2:

[image]

TestDisk3:

[image]

GDisk Output:

[image]

Comment: Windows reserved is just unformatted space for Windows to store some settings. Not accessible. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Reserved_Partition On a data drive, Microsoft makes it the first partition. Normally 128MB. But if drive was converted from MBR to gpt, then it was erased. Post this: `sudo parted -l`.

Comment: Thanks so much for offering to help, here is the original drive that got whacked, sdd.

Model: ATA ST2000DX002-2DV1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdd: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  608MB  607MB  primary  ntfs         boot

Comment: In BIOS Windows the system partition is just the Boot partition, normally not seen in Windows. Older drives used 100MB, newer 4K drives used larger Boot. But only used with old BIOS/MBR configuration. Windows has required vendors to install in UEFI with gpt partitioning since 2012. Does testdisk show old partitions. If changed a lot, you have to select correct combination. http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk  & https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step  Better to post any terminal output in question, not comments, so can be formatted & legible.

Comment: Hi @oldfred, sorry about that. I updated the original post with screen shots. I dont know what to do next.

Comment: If deeper search shows any files, immediately copy them to another working drive & partition. You may not get them again. I see hybrid. When Windows converts a gpt drive to MBR, it leaves the backup gpt partition table (why I always suggest gpt unless very old BIOS Windows) and then Linux tools get confused if MBR or gpt. Post this in question: `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdd` if drive is sdd or whichever drive it is.

Comment: I updated post again with GDisk output for that drive.

Comment: Not sure but I think invalid gpt, is typical of a Windows conversion of a drive from gpt to MBR. It leaves backup gpt or old data. But I thought gdisk might see backup gpt and offer to use it.

Comment: It sounds like there is no easy fix for this? I feel I really screwed up when I connected the backup drive I found and booted to Windows instead of Linux to gather the files and put on a NTFS drive. I had no idea Windows was capable of destroying a drive like this. Any other advice?

Comment: Did testdisk not show files with deeper search? Windows does not see Linux partiitons, so can overwrite them as if not seen. But Linux does similar if Windows fast start up is on, so Windows not seen, and you install to "blank" drive erasing Windows. Always have good backups before any system change, but you should have backups anyway.

Comment: Hi, just to be clear, there was no install here on this destruction of my backup EXT4 drive. I just connected the drive thru SATA and booted up. A windows partition ended up on the drive and now LINUX cannot mount or view any of the filesystem. How is this acceptable for an OS to do this? If it doesnt understand the drive it shouldnt nuke it by adding a partition to it.

Comment: What happened was, my up to date drive was compromised during my father installing windows and resetting the BIOS. I'm not sure which did it in. My backup drive I had, all I did was plug it in via SATA and that got whacked too. I dont see anything in my BIOS about fast boot. Right now I have some recovered data from EaseUS file recovery, but some files are damaged, video file incomplete. Should I re-attempt file recovery in LINUX on a new drive with photorec? Will that have better results?

Comment: IMO just format the hard drive(s) where operating systems are stored and reinstall both operating systems- Windows first.  There is so much confusion at this point that a fresh start will just be faster and easier.  Plus, when you do it yourself, you will have a better understanding of your system.

Comment: Windows in BIOS boot mode converts gpt drives to MBR(msdos), and puts the primary NTFS boot partition's on the default drive. So even if installing Windows to sdb, but if BIOS still set to boot from sda, then Windows will put a boot partition on sda, no matter what was there. Microsoft has required vendors to install Windows in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives since Windows 8 released in 2012. So most hardware is now UEFI. But users can install in old BIOS/MBR mode, but probably should not. Manufacturers are starting to release UEFI class 3 systems that have no CSM/BIOS/Legacy mode.

Comment: Now I am really confused, because this happened on sdd not sda. Why is this happening only to EXT4 drives and not NTFS drives i have mounted? On the original hybrid drive i found a full windows filesystem, 607MB on the windows partition, so I was convinced my father had a mistaken install. The backup drive which I thought would be OK has only a 17MB windows partition on it now. Is there any way to save/fix either drive?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a drive that had about 18 of the 20 years worth of data on it in my closet and restored that way, I didn't put too much on it in the last 2 years.

What windows does to drives it cant identify is unacceptable, there should be interaction with the user before adding boot partitions. I didn't have this issue with NTFS drives on the system. Shame on Microsoft. What happened to me shouldn't happen.

Recovering individual files, especially media files, from EXT4 is not pretty.
Partial files and corruption all over the place.
I was lucky I didn't throw out or reformat all of my old drives or I would have been totally screwed. I only lost a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone runs into this issue, I was able to recover my ext4 drive after windows borked (after mounting from wsl2)

I used testdisk.

```
sudo testdisk
# arrow key down to drive
# select filesystem None
# select Superblock
```

which gave me this information for recovering disk:

```
TestDisk 7.1, Data Recovery Utility, July 2019
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
https://www.cgsecurity.org

Disk /dev/nvme4n1 - 2000 GB / 1863 GiB - CHS 1907729 64 32

     Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors

  ext4                     0   0  1 1907729   5 16 3907029168 [990-ML]
superblock 0, blocksize=4096 [990-ML]
superblock 32768, blocksize=4096 [990-ML]
superblock 98304, blocksize=4096 [990-ML]
superblock 163840, blocksize=4096 [990-ML]
superblock 229376, blocksize=4096 [990-ML]
superblock 294912, blocksize=4096 [990-ML]
superblock 819200, blocksize=4096 [990-ML]
superblock 884736, blocksize=4096 [990-ML]
superblock 1605632, blocksize=4096 [990-ML]
superblock 2654208, blocksize=4096 [990-ML]

To repair the filesystem using alternate superblock, run
fsck.ext4 -p -b superblock -B blocksize device
```

From that information, I ran this command in my terminal:

```
sudo fsck.ext4 -p -b 32768 -B 4096 /dev/nvme4n1
```

I ran the fsck.ext4 using the first superblock "32768", and the filesystem reappeared, and I can mount and browse in Ubuntu now.

Sheesh that was scary. Never again using WSL.